# datepicker selenium javascipt using

Tags: node.js, selenium

[image: calendar code]

To automate a datepicker, I tried using `element.setvalue("12/12/2021")`

Has anyone tried the datepicker by clicking on the dates on the modal using javascript? Do you start selecting the year and then click on the arrows for month?

Answer (score 0):

- The datepicker has an input element which you can fill text on. This is my code:

> ```
> Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
> actions.moveToElement(element);
> actions.click();
> actions.sendKeys(pickupDateTime);
> actions.build().perform();
> ```

- And then sendKeys "Enter" to close datePicker.

`inputElement.sendkeys(Keys.ENTER);`

Comment: Yeah. I am able to do that. But I am wondering if we can use the actual datepicker elements like month, year date to automate

Comment: In my opinion, if the datepicker is created by our company, we should test it. I will ask the dev team to support. 
If it is the third-party tool/ framework, we just do the simplest way that does not affect user behaviour.